# AWS EC2 Marathon-Mesos Failing to Run Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I have Marathon/Mesos master set up on a single AWS EC2 instance. I also have a Mesos agent running on a non-AWS external machine <strike>with strict firewall rules</strike> (all ports are open between the two).

The agent registers itself with the master correctly. When I start a Marathon app it creates a Docker task. The Docker image specified is successfully pulled from Docker Hub on the agent machine, **but it never runs** for some reason... I don't see any relevant information in the Mesos master logs; only that the 'task failed'. When I run the Docker image on the Mesos agent machine manually (with the parameters I specified in my Marathon configuration) it runs perfectly fine. I have the same configuration running on different machines in a local network and Marathon deploys apps without any issues. I'm not sure what to try next.

Does the Mesos agent need to connect directly to Marathon for some reason? I assumed that communication with the Mesos master was all that was needed.

Mesos task stderr (updated 3/24/2017):

```
I0324 16:17:22.286581  7304 fetcher.cpp:498] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"\/tmp\/mesos\/fetch\/slaves\/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"executable":false,"extract":true,"value":"file:\/\/\/etc\/mesos\/auth\/docker.tar.gz"}}],"sandbox_directory":"\/var\/lib\/mesos\/slaves\/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0\/frameworks\/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000\/executors\/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122\/runs\/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308"}
I0324 16:17:22.290792  7304 fetcher.cpp:409] Fetching URI 'file:///etc/mesos/auth/docker.tar.gz'
I0324 16:17:22.290828  7304 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I0324 16:17:22.290864  7304 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'file:///etc/mesos/auth/docker.tar.gz'
I0324 16:17:22.290887  7304 fetcher.cpp:167] Copying resource with command:cp '/etc/mesos/auth/docker.tar.gz' '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308/docker.tar.gz'
I0324 16:17:22.295295  7304 fetcher.cpp:84] Extracting with command: tar -C '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308' -xf '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308/docker.tar.gz'
I0324 16:17:22.302006  7304 fetcher.cpp:92] Extracted '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308/docker.tar.gz' into '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308'
I0324 16:17:22.302070  7304 fetcher.cpp:547] Fetched 'file:///etc/mesos/auth/docker.tar.gz' to '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_eureka-discovery-service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308/docker.tar.gz'
I0324 16:17:23.632253  7328 openssl.cpp:416] CA file path is unspecified! NOTE: Set CA file path with LIBPROCESS_SSL_CA_FILE=<filepath>
I0324 16:17:23.632388  7328 openssl.cpp:421] CA directory path unspecified! NOTE: Set CA directory path with LIBPROCESS_SSL_CA_DIR=<dirpath>
I0324 16:17:23.632400  7328 openssl.cpp:426] Will not verify peer certificate!
NOTE: Set LIBPROCESS_SSL_VERIFY_CERT=1 to enable peer certificate verification
I0324 16:17:23.632407  7328 openssl.cpp:432] Will only verify peer certificate if presented!
NOTE: Set LIBPROCESS_SSL_REQUIRE_CERT=1 to require peer certificate verification
I0324 16:17:23.636519  7328 exec.cpp:162] Version: 1.1.0
I0324 16:19:30.956297  7332 exec.cpp:496] Agent exited ... shutting down
E0324 16:19:30.956517  7337 process.cpp:2154] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 7: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Mesos agent log (updated 3/24/2017):

```
I0324 16:16:04.465209  7244 linux_launcher.cpp:150] Using /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer as the freezer hierarchy for the Linux launcher
I0324 16:16:04.469977  7277 slave.cpp:208] Mesos agent started on (1)@external.public.ip.addr:5051
I0324 16:16:04.470039  7277 slave.cpp:209] Flags at startup: --advertise_ip="external.public.ip.addr" --appc_simple_discovery_uri_prefix="http://" --appc_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/appc" --attributes="node:external-hostname" --authenticate_http_readonly="false" --authenticate_http_readwrite="false" --authenticatee="crammd5" --authentication_backoff_factor="1secs" --authorizer="local" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" --cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="docker,mesos" --credential="/etc/mesos/auth/credential" --default_role="*" --disk_watch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_registry="https://registry-1.docker.io" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --docker_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/docker" --docker_volume_checkpoint_dir="/var/run/mesos/isolators/docker/volume" --enforce_container_disk_quota="false" --executor_environment_variables="{"SSL_CERT_FILE":"\/etc\/mesos\/ssl\/mesos.pem","SSL_ENABLED":"true","SSL_KEY_FILE":"\/etc\/mesos\/ssl\/mesos.key"}" --executor_registration_timeout="5mins" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" --hadoop_home="" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --http_command_executor="false" --image_provisioner_backend="copy" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher="linux" --launcher_dir="/usr/libexec/mesos" --log_dir="/var/log/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --master="zk://aws.public.ip.addr:2181/mesos" --max_completed_executors_per_framework="150" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --port="5051" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registration_backoff_factor="1secs" --resources="ports:[45000-45300]" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --runtime_dir="/var/run/mesos" --sandbox_directory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --strict="true" --switch_user="true" --systemd_enable_support="true" --systemd_runtime_directory="/run/systemd/system" --version="false" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos"
I0324 16:16:04.470541  7277 credentials.hpp:86] Loading credential for authentication from '/etc/mesos/auth/credential'
I0324 16:16:04.475219  7277 slave.cpp:346] Agent using credential for: user
I0324 16:16:04.476274  7277 slave.cpp:533] Agent resources: ports(*):[45000-45300]; cpus(*):2; mem(*):1000; disk(*):17933
I0324 16:16:04.476395  7277 slave.cpp:541] Agent attributes: [ node=external-hostname ]
I0324 16:16:04.476418  7277 slave.cpp:546] Agent hostname: external-hostname.com
I0324 16:16:04.478091  7273 state.cpp:57] Recovering state from '/var/lib/mesos/meta'
I0324 16:16:04.478227  7273 state.cpp:698] No committed checkpointed resources found at '/var/lib/mesos/meta/resources/resources.info'
I0324 16:16:04.478538  7273 state.cpp:100] Failed to find the latest agent from '/var/lib/mesos/meta'
I0324 16:16:04.478847  7273 status_update_manager.cpp:203] Recovering status update manager
I0324 16:16:04.479176  7274 docker.cpp:764] Recovering Docker containers
I0324 16:16:04.479267  7273 containerizer.cpp:555] Recovering containerizer
I0324 16:16:04.483211  7273 provisioner.cpp:253] Provisioner recovery complete
I0324 16:16:04.556633  7273 slave.cpp:5281] Finished recovery
I0324 16:16:04.557209  7273 slave.cpp:5314] Garbage collecting old agent 58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S0
I0324 16:16:04.557435  7273 slave.cpp:5314] Garbage collecting old agent 58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S1
I0324 16:16:04.557416  7271 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S0' for gc 6.99999354992days in the future
I0324 16:16:04.557569  7271 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S0' for gc 6.99999354837926days in the future
I0324 16:16:04.557613  7271 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S1' for gc 6.99999354770963days in the future
I0324 16:16:04.557642  7271 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/58f98804-d979-414c-99f0-b9453a64d133-S1' for gc 6.99999354741926days in the future
I0324 16:16:04.567785  7273 group.cpp:340] Group process (zookeeper-group(1)@external.public.ip.addr:5051) connected to ZooKeeper
I0324 16:16:04.567862  7273 group.cpp:828] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0324 16:16:04.567885  7273 group.cpp:418] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0324 16:16:04.651988  7272 detector.cpp:152] Detected a new leader: (id='17')
I0324 16:16:04.652292  7272 group.cpp:697] Trying to get '/mesos/json.info_0000000017' in ZooKeeper
I0324 16:16:04.694649  7272 zookeeper.cpp:259] A new leading master (UPID=master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050) is detected
I0324 16:16:04.694806  7272 slave.cpp:915] New master detected at master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050
I0324 16:16:04.694839  7272 slave.cpp:974] Authenticating with master master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050
I0324 16:16:04.694878  7275 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
I0324 16:16:04.695226  7272 slave.cpp:985] Using default CRAM-MD5 authenticatee
I0324 16:16:04.695358  7272 slave.cpp:947] Detecting new master
I0324 16:16:04.695709  7272 authenticatee.cpp:97] Initializing client SASL
I0324 16:16:04.697775  7272 authenticatee.cpp:121] Creating new client SASL connection
I0324 16:16:04.994292  7275 authenticatee.cpp:213] Received SASL authentication mechanisms: CRAM-MD5
I0324 16:16:04.994408  7275 authenticatee.cpp:239] Attempting to authenticate with mechanism 'CRAM-MD5'
I0324 16:16:05.073065  7270 authenticatee.cpp:259] Received SASL authentication step
I0324 16:16:05.119057  7274 authenticatee.cpp:299] Authentication success
I0324 16:16:05.119209  7274 slave.cpp:1069] Successfully authenticated with master master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050
I0324 16:16:05.167603  7270 slave.cpp:1115] Registered with master master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050; given agent ID 5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0
I0324 16:16:05.167878  7277 status_update_manager.cpp:184] Resuming sending status updates
I0324 16:16:05.168328  7270 slave.cpp:1175] Forwarding total oversubscribed resources {}
I0324 16:17:04.477218  7276 slave.cpp:5044] Current disk usage 13.80%. Max allowed age: 5.334189423043843days
I0324 16:17:22.210543  7277 slave.cpp:1539] Got assigned task 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:17:22.212566  7277 slave.cpp:1701] Launching task 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:17:22.214239  7277 paths.cpp:536] Trying to chown '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308' to user 'root'
I0324 16:17:22.222681  7277 slave.cpp:6179] Launching executor 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308'
I0324 16:17:22.224074  7277 slave.cpp:1987] Queued task 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for executor 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:17:22.230206  7277 docker.cpp:1022] Starting container '49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308' for task 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' (and executor 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122') of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:17:23.576908  7271 docker.cpp:670] Checkpointing pid 7328 to '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308/pids/forked.pid'
I0324 16:18:04.478448  7270 slave.cpp:5044] Current disk usage 13.80%. Max allowed age: 5.334151467743322days
I0324 16:19:04.479935  7273 slave.cpp:5044] Current disk usage 13.80%. Max allowed age: 5.334151467743322days
I0324 16:19:30.984578  7271 docker.cpp:2164] Executor for container 49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308 has exited
I0324 16:19:30.984671  7271 docker.cpp:1887] Destroying container 49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308
I0324 16:19:30.984764  7271 docker.cpp:2014] Running docker stop on container 49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308
I0324 16:19:30.985744  7273 slave.cpp:4542] Executor 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000 exited with status 0
I0324 16:19:30.987206  7273 slave.cpp:3634] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
W0324 16:19:30.987942  7270 docker.cpp:1411] Ignoring updating unknown container 49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308
I0324 16:19:30.988471  7271 status_update_manager.cpp:323] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:30.988976  7271 status_update_manager.cpp:832] Checkpointing UPDATE for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:30.989449  7275 slave.cpp:4051] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000 to master@aws.public.ip.addr:5050
I0324 16:19:31.067975  7272 status_update_manager.cpp:395] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:31.068097  7272 status_update_manager.cpp:832] Checkpointing ACK for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: a4edf8e3-33db-4d76-95c4-12e1ad154b84) for task external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122 of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:31.068485  7272 slave.cpp:4646] Cleaning up executor 'external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:31.068881  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308' for gc 6.99999920398222days in the future
I0324 16:19:31.068966  7272 slave.cpp:4734] Cleaning up framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:31.068994  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for gc 6.99999920297481days in the future
I0324 16:19:31.069028  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/49ac20eb-8d9a-4605-903c-ffe700475308' for gc 6.99999920246518days in the future
I0324 16:19:31.069054  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.94f42881-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for gc 6.99999920205926days in the future
I0324 16:19:31.069083  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000' for gc 6.99999920099556days in the future
I0324 16:19:31.069087  7272 status_update_manager.cpp:285] Closing status update streams for framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:31.069116  7275 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000' for gc 6.99999920064889days in the future
I0324 16:19:32.085212  7275 slave.cpp:1539] Got assigned task 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:32.086843  7275 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000' from gc
I0324 16:19:32.086974  7275 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000' from gc
I0324 16:19:32.087297  7274 slave.cpp:1701] Launching task 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:32.089426  7274 paths.cpp:536] Trying to chown '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/4de6d12d-a313-4921-b40b-245b57b2a886' to user 'root'
I0324 16:19:32.098151  7274 slave.cpp:6179] Launching executor 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/4de6d12d-a313-4921-b40b-245b57b2a886'
I0324 16:19:32.100893  7274 slave.cpp:1987] Queued task 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' for executor 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:32.106264  7277 docker.cpp:1022] Starting container '4de6d12d-a313-4921-b40b-245b57b2a886' for task 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122' (and executor 'external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122') of framework 3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000
I0324 16:19:33.403033  7273 docker.cpp:670] Checkpointing pid 7367 to '/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/5086ccee-b936-4c32-884e-479a75e6a13e-S0/frameworks/3b9e3459-97f0-4f98-8510-50bdf55d4d7b-0000/executors/external-hostname_service.e2757782-10df-11e7-97c5-be1a04dcc122/runs/4de6d12d-a313-4921-b40b-245b57b2a886/pids/forked.pid'
I0324 16:20:04.481197  7271 slave.cpp:5044] Current disk usage 13.80%. Max allowed age: 5.334241611582060days
```

For marathon logs, see **[HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/marathon-framework/AXnu2QzW5E8)** (I reached the character limit for this post)

Versions: Marathon 1.3.6 and Mesos 1.1.0

3/24/2017 Update notes: This problem is exclusive to having Marathon and the Mesos master on an AWS EC2 instance. If I move them to some other external machine I don't have any issues. I'm *guessing* that at some point in the process Mesos is using the EC2's private ip address even though I specify its public ip address with the flag *advertise_ip*.

Comment: `Executor for container... has exited` Maybe your executor cannot connect with agent? Can you disable firewall on this host?

Comment: I disabled the firewall temporarily and the agent log contains the same 'Executor for container... has exited'. Could it be related to the masters being on EC2 instances?

Comment: Do you have marathon health checks for the application?  Can you paste in the marathon logs as well?

Comment: I don't have marathon health checks for the application. I added the marathon logs to my post on the marathon-framework google group (see link added to my post).